# Angular 2 rerender Form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

If I delete a form control from my form I have the problem that the form always is invalid.

But if I delete a char from another input field and add the same char again (in order to create a change event) the form is valid as it has to be.

How can I refresh the form after the deletion of the form control?

Many Thanks

Comment: if you want to update *and* re-run the form validation mechanism, you can do `myFrom.updateValueAndValidity()`

Comment: what si your code for deleting a form control?

Comment: I already tried form.updateValueAndValidity(). Currently I remove it with splice from formArray and from data array

Comment: do I have to set also the params? this.synonymsForm.updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf: false, emitEvent: true});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found a solution. But I dont think that this is the only way to do it.

In order to force the rerender process I patch the value with the current one:

```
myForm.patchValue(myForm.value, {onlySelf: false, emitEvent: true});
```